# How to call a function when I run nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need my server to go up, call a function then go down.
From what I've seen on the web I should use this section of code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.on('listening', () => {
  console.log("Server up...");
  console.log("Server going down...");
});
```

but for some reason this does not work for me.
The program does go up but the logs are not written.

Comment: If you want your server to stop, you need some code to stop it as in `server.close()` where `server` is your server object which you don't show code for creating.  Also, I don't know what you're trying to do with `app.on('listening', ...)`.  The `app` is not your server when using Express.  The server comes from `const server = app.listen(80)` when using Express.

Comment: Ok, this should not be the server. What I need is to call a function when I run start this app. How do I do that?

Comment: If you just want to call a function when you start this app, just call the function at the appropriate place in your code.  Why can't you just call the function when you want to call it?  Your question is completely unclear what you're trying to do.  Clear questions here usually get very quick answers.  Unclear questions get downvoted or closed.  Please edit your question to describe very clearly what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(3000);
//call whatever function you need here
server.close(() => console.log("Server going down..."));
```

First we start the server using [app.listen](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) and later when you want to close it just do server.close()